# Как сделать кнопку like для поста wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, плагин, button, like

Как сделать кнопку like для поста wordpress?

Кнопка НЕ из соцсети. Просто wp-кнопка. Если кто знает плагин, с помощью которого подобное можно реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста, но лучше без плагина.

Вот так выглядит сверстанная кнопка

[image: Вот так выглядит сверстанная кнопка]

Answer (score 1):

Wp_PostRatings попробуй. Есть возможность менять стили забитых в плагин кнопок.